# Using XML schemas as OO inheritance (JAXB) - possible?

Tags: xml, xsd, jaxb, restriction

I have a set of complex types in my XML schema file. Basically I have a bunch of "response" objects. Each response object follows the same general format but in more specific ways. So, for example:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="Transition">
  <xsd:restriction base="xsd:string"/>
</xsd:simpleType>
<xsd:complexType name="ResponseBlock"/>
<xsd:complexType name="Response">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:sequence>
      <xsd:element name="transition" type="dto:Transition"/>
      <xsd:element name="data" type="dto:ResponseBlock"/>
    </xsd:sequence>
 </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

I'd like to make it possible to have a "subclass" of this where the "transition" and "ResponseBlock" are replaced with valid "subclasses" of each of those types. I.e. I have already derived them by restriction/extension and want to include them in a Response which is itself derived by restriction:

```
<xsd:simpleType name="IDTransition">
  <xsd:restriction base="dto:Transition">
   <xsd:enumeration value="NEXT_PAGE"/>
  </xsd:restriction>
</xsd:simpleType>

<xsd:complexType name="IDResponseBlock">
  <xsd:complexContent>
    <xsd:extension base="dto:ResponseBlock">
      <xsd:sequence>
        <xsd:element type="xsd:int" name="userID"/>
        <xsd:element type="xsd:string" name="userName"/>
      </xsd:sequence>
    </xsd:extension>
  </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>

<xsd:complexType name="IDResponse">
   <xsd:complexContent>
      <xsd:restriction base="Response">
         <xsd:sequence>
           <xsd:element name="transition" type="dto:IDTransition"/>
           <xsd:element name="data" type="dto:IDResponseBlock"/>
         </xsd:sequence>
      </xsd:restriction>
   </xsd:complexContent>
</xsd:complexType>
```

This way, using JAXB, I could generate a fully object-oriented inheritance structure. But it doesn't seem to compile; Eclipse is showing an error:

derivation-ok-restriction.5.4.2: Error for type 'IDResponse'.  The particle of the type is not a valid restriction of the particle of the base. 
rcase-Recurse.2: There is not a complete functional mapping between the particles.

Any ideas on how I can accomplish this?

Answer (score 5):

The following articles are related to JAXB and Inheritance:

- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-xsitype.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-using-substitution.html
- http://bdoughan.blogspot.com/2010/11/jaxb-and-inheritance-moxy-extension.html

Comment: Thanks very much for the links. Unfortunately none of them seem to address this particular situation. The first link is essentially what I'm already doing now. The second is for global elements rather than types. And the third concentrates on generating XML from Java rather than vice versa. 8-(

Answer (score 0):

If IDResponse is extending Response, "complexType" should be "complexContent", and "restriction" should be "extension".

Comment: "complexType" was a typo, it was indeed complexContent.
My issue is that, to my understanding, "extension" means you are *adding on* to the existing fields, while "restriction" means you are *changing* them. I want to change the fields to use "subclasses" rather than the original, broader definitions. I'm just not sure this is possible.

Comment: It is not clear what kind of class hierarchy you are trying to describe in the XSD. Perhaps a diagram of the hierarchy would help communicate your problem.

Comment: OK, looking again it seems like this isn't possible... I thought Java could allow inheritance with enums, but it doesn't. Ah well... a bit messier than I'd like but it works as is. 8-)